# select row only when checkbox is clicked ExtjS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

In an ExtJS 4.1 grid that uses CheckboxModel as a selection model, when you click on an entire row, that row is selected (and the corresponding checkbox is checked). Is there a way that I can prevent that default behaviour from happening and permit row selection only when the checkbox for a corresponding row is clicked (as opposed to when clicking the entire row)?

Again I'm using ExtJS version 4.1

Thanks for any help

**Note:** My grid also has the [CellEditing plugin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing) attached to it. I don't want the row to be selected when the CellEditing plugin gets activated when I click on a cell.

Answer (score 2):

Try the checkOnly property on your CheckBoxModel:

```
var sm = new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel({
    checkOnly: true
});
```

From the documentation:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-cfg-checkOnly

```
checkOnly : Boolean

True if rows can only be selected by clicking on the checkbox column.

Defaults to: false
```

Please see my fiddle here for a working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vue

**Update**

To change the CheckBoxModel checkOnly mode after the grid has been rendered:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().checkOnly = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that the CheckboxModel has already been defined and I don't have access to the initialization code. How do I change that config without having access to the code where it was initialized (like using a setCheckOnly method or something)?

Comment: Yes, you can add checkOnly after the CheckBoxModel has been defined by setting checkOnly to true. I've updated the answer and fiddle to show this.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that my grid also has the CellEditing plugin (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing). When I click on a column to activate the CellEditing plugin, the corresponding row gets selected including the checkbox for that row (on any other columns it works). Thanks for any help

Comment: I know of a solution for the 4.2 series (demonstrated here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8jp) but unfortunately not 4.1