# prevent row select on cell click ExtJS 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have an ExtJS grid that has the CellEditing plugin attached to it. When I click on a cell to edit its content, the entire row is selected.

How do I prevent a row from being selected when I click on an editable cell in my grid?

I'm using ExtJS 4.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to your previous question - ["select row only when checkbox is clicked ExtjS 4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288030/select-row-only-when-checkbox-is-clicked-extjs-4), so I found a really hacky way - using the `beforeselect`, `beforeedit`, `edit` and `canceledit`  events like:

```
listeners: (function(){
    var editing;

    return {
        beforeselect: function(){
            return !editing;
        },
        beforeedit: function(){
            editing = true;
        },
        edit: function(){
            editing = false;
        },
        canceledit: function(){
            editing = false;
        }
    }
}())
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/100a

Comment: Thanks but how do I disable edits on rows that are selected?